# Facebook App Invite Notification Issue

Tags: ios, facebook, notifications, push

I have implemented the Facebook app invite in my application.

App Invite implementation code:

```
 FBSDKAppInviteContent *content1 =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content1.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/..3417..."];
 [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:viewController withContent:content1 delegate:self];
```

1. I have created the appLinkURL from App Link Tool provided by Facebook.
2. Currently i have not provided iPhone Store ID as application is under development.

**Issue:**

-User is not receiving any Push Notification.But app invite were present in the More->Apps->App Invitations

1. I have created two test user both are friend with each other and both have not authorized the application.
2. On one device the application was not installed currently.
3. On both devices Facebook app was installed and user were logged to the Facebook app.

But user did not receive any push notification.

And one more thing : This feature need review from Facebook ??
Any help.

Comment: this is only code i have used

Comment: FBID is not required for this feature. i think

Comment: Please make sure you have ios enabled in your Facebook Application's app center listed platforms as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *App Setting* on Facebook developer console, I forgot to add iOS AppID. After configuring that, I was able to see the notification in notification tab of Facebook mobile app. This feature do not require approval from Facebook.